# Array integer[]: how to get all distinct values in a table and count them?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array, set-returning-functions

I'm not so good with SQL (PostgreSQL). Here is what I want to do:

I have a table, fields:

```
id SERIAL
inet INET
ports integer[]

 id |    inet    | ports 
----+------------+------------
  2 | 1.2.2.1    | {80}
  1 | 1.2.3.4    | {80,12}
  ...
```

How can I

1. get all used "ports" values in this table: 80, 12
2. count how many inet addresses are on specific port:

Like this:

```
  port  | count
--------+------------
 12     | 1
 80     | 2
  ...
```

---

If anyone is looking for a Django version of it:

```
class Unnest(Func):
    function = 'UNNEST'

Model.objects \
.annotate(port=Unnest('ports', distinct=True)) \
.values('port') \
.annotate(count=Count('port')) \
.order_by('-count', '-port')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `UNNEST`.

```
select unnest(ports) as port, count(*) from foo group by port;
```

Using more than one UNNEST in the same query (or the same select list, anyway) is confusing and is probably best avoided.

Answer (score 4):

It's cleaner to use set returning functions in the `FROM` clause where possible. The SQL standard does not allow them in the `SELECT` list. And it's almost always possible since we have `LATERAL` joins.

```
SELECT port, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl t, unnest(t.ports) AS port  -- implicit LATERAL join
GROUP  BY port;
```

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

But I have to concede that the "quick-and-dirty" variant [@Jeff provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126413/3684) is typically *faster*.